# WP_Query и пагинация

Tags: php, wordpress

Я сделал такой WP_Query, но почему-то не выводится пагинация.

В archive-product вывел такой WP Query

```
  $wp_query = new wp_query( array(
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'paged' => get_query_var('paged'),
    'posts_per_page' => 9,
    'orderby'      => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_key'      => 'lenght',
    'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            $year_query,
            $lenght_query,
        )
    ),
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(

        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                        'field' => 'id',
                        'terms' => $cateID

        ),
        
        $builder_query, 
        $guests_query, 
        $location_query, 

        $cond_query, 
        $cabins_query, 
        $type_query,
       
    ),

    ));

if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <!-- цикл -->
    <?php while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post(); 
                 wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
      endwhile; ?>

      
   
    <!-- конец цикла -->
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

В function.php вставил такой код для вывода пагинации (украдено с WP KAMA)

```
function my_pagenavi() {
    global $wp_query;

    $big = 999999999; // уникальное число для замены

    $args = array(
        'base'    => str_replace( $big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link( $big ) ),
        'format'  => '',
        'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
        'total'   => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
    );

    $result = paginate_links( $args );

    // удаляем добавку к пагинации для первой страницы
    $result = preg_replace( '~/page/1/?([\'"])~', '', $result );

    echo $result;
}
```

Но пагинация не выводится.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: https://www.kobzarev.com/wordpress/pagination-doesnt-work/

Answer (score 0):

Функцию `my_pagenavi()` вызвайте там, где должна быть пагинация.

Вот так:

```
echo my_pagenavi();
```